# Toggle Map Tips with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, maptips

I want to display "map tips" in QGIS with python for my custom map canvas `QgsMapCanvas()`.

How can I do this? I can switch manually with **View/Map Tips** but it won't work with my custom canvas in my plugin, it works only with `iface.mapCanvas()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if there's another way, but this is how I've implemented it.

You need these three functions (make sure you import the required QGIS and Qt4 classes before):

```
def createMapTips( self ):
    """ Create MapTips on the map """
    self.timerMapTips = QTimer( self.canvas )
    self.mapTip = QgsMapTip()
    self.connect( self.canvas, SIGNAL( "xyCoordinates(const QgsPoint&)" ),
        self.mapTipXYChanged )
    self.connect( self.timerMapTips, SIGNAL( "timeout()" ),
        self.showMapTip )

def mapTipXYChanged( self, p ):
    """ SLOT. Initialize the Timer to show MapTips on the map """
    if self.canvas.underMouse(): # Only if mouse is over the map
        # Here you could check if your custom MapTips button is active or sth
        self.lastMapPosition = QgsPoint( p.x(), p.y() )
        self.mapTip.clear( self.canvas )
        self.timerMapTips.start( 750 ) # time in milliseconds

def showMapTip( self ):
    """ SLOT. Show  MapTips on the map """
    self.timerMapTips.stop()

    if self.canvas.underMouse(): 
        # Here you could check if your custom MapTips button is active or sth
        pointQgs = self.lastMapPosition
        pointQt = self.canvas.mouseLastXY()
        self.mapTip.showMapTip( self.layer, pointQgs, pointQt,
            self.canvas )
```

You would also need to set a layer, and probably a display field:

```
self.layer = layer # For MapTips
self.layer.setDisplayField('NMG')
```

Finally, initialize the `createMapTips` function, for example, after you set your base layer and its display field.

```
self.createMapTips()
```

You should be able to see map tips on your custom mapCanvas like this:

[image]

Notice that you could need some GUI controls to help users use and configure map tips. For example, a button to enable/disable them and a *comboBox* for users to choose the display field, but, of course, it would depend on your use case.

Comment: classes to be imported for this one please

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `iface.actionMapTips().trigger()` and in QGIS 3.x for layer field description use `layer.setDisplayExpression('field_name')`

Also if you want to create a function to control to check and uncheck use that:

```
iface.actionMapTips().setChecked(True)
```