# Setting delay of map tips in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, maptips

Is it possible to set the delay timer when hovering the cursor over maptips?

It seems like there's a one second delay as shown below but I would like to have it appear instantly instead.

[image: Maptips]

---

Using QGIS 2.18.17 and 3.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not change it in the GUI, as it is hard-coded. We can see in `qgisapp.cpp, createMapTips()`

```
 // set the interval to 0.850 seconds - timer will be started next time the mouse moves
  mpMapTipsTimer->setInterval( 850 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will take a look and see if it is somehow exposed to the API :)

Comment: Did u check this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157894/how-to-toggle-map-tips-with-pyqgis?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to set the map tip delay from **QGIS 3.2**:

[image: Map tips delay option]